# Is there a one-key command to insert before the first character of the line?

Tags: key-bindings, insert-mode, normal-mode

I can use <kbd>^</kbd>, <kbd>i</kbd> to get into insert mode from normal mode.

But I was wondering if there's a shorter way to do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you need is `I` (uppercase letter `i`). From [`:help I`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/insert.txt.html#I)

```
I           Insert text before the first non-blank in the line
            [count] times.
```